# About Galois extensions contained in inseparable extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to solve exercise 28 from chapter 14 of Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra, which says the following:

---

28. Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over the field $F$, let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ in $L$. If $K$ is any Galois extension of $F$ contained in $L$, show that the polynomial $f(x)$ splits into a product of $m$ irreducible polynomials each of degree $d$ over $K$, where $m=[F(\alpha)\cap K:F]$ and $d=[K(\alpha):K]$. [If $H$ is the subgroup of the Galois group of $L$ over $F$ corresponding to $K$ then the factors of $f(x)$ over $K$ correspond to the orbits of $H$ on the roots of $f(x)$. Then use Exercise 9 of Section 4.1.]

---

After some effort, I managed to write a proof of this result for the case where $f(x)$ is separable, since in this case, $L/F$ is a Galois extension and I can make use of the Galois correspondence. The case where $f(x)$ is inseparable remains. In this case, I don't know how to proceed. My first attempt was to try to use the fact that $L$ contains $K$ (which is Galois over $F$, hence separable) to deduce that $L/F$ is separable, but I couldn't prove it, which led me to the following question:

- Are there finite Galois extensions contained in inseparable extensions? If so, can you give me an example?

The hint given in the exercise assumes that the Galois group of $L$ over $F$ is well-defined, meaning that $L/F$ is Galois. So, I wonder if I should assume that $f(x)$ (and consequently, $L/F$) is indeed separable. My other questions are:

- Is this result true if $f(x)$ is not separable? If so, how to prove this result in that case? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: The Galois group of $L$ over $F$ is just the (finite) group of automorphism of $L$ fixing $F$ pointwise. Note that $L/F$ is Galois if and only if $F$ is the fixed field of the Galois group. The subgroup $H$ in the hint is the subgroup fixing $K$ pointwise.

Comment: Please do not use pictures to convey critical information not otherwise contained in your post. [Here is the explanation for why you should avoid this.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)